# Visual Studio не находит библиотеку

Tags: visual-studio, компоновщик

При сборке проекта получаю ошибку

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libEGL.lib'

Путь к библиотеке указан

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она там лежит

```
D:\...Project\SDK\src\demo\windows_demo>dir ..\..\..\bin\16.0\x64\Debug\*.lib
 Том в устройстве D имеет метку Sources
 Серийный номер тома: 64FF-EA83

 Содержимое папки D:\Sources\Project\SDK\bin\16.0\x64\Debug

03.10.2017  12:37            15 814 libEGL.lib
03.10.2017  12:37           227 920 libGLESv2.lib
```

Чего еще не хватает?

Смотрел через ProcMon - библиотека ищется в нескольких путях Program Files и в каталоге проекта. Такое ощущение, что Additional Library Directories просто игнорируется

Платформа и конфигурация установлены корректно

Версия студии

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
> Version 16.10.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используется относительный путь, но делается странное предположение о том, относительно чего этот путь относительный. Вместо этого следует всегда использовать абсолютные пути, а чтобы не хардкодить пути на конкретной машине, следует использовать пути, заданные от одного из известных расположений, например относительно папки решения `$(SolutionDir)` или проекта `$(ProjectDir)`. В данном случае наверное должно быть что-то подобное `$(ProjectDir)\SDK\bin\16.0\x64\Debug\`

И в конце надо не забывать прописывать `%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)`, чтобы свойства наследовались от ранее включенных блоков свойств.

Comment: Спасибо. `$(ProjectDir)` помог. Проект не мой. Оказалось, что в нем сам файл проекта лежит в подпапке. А с `$(ProjectDir)` я увидел реальній путь